# Transparent windows bug in PhpStorm, Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, phpstorm

There's a bug on a particular machine. Sometimes PhpStorm's window gets completely transparent, no visible content.

[image: Screen]

Any idea what it is and how to fix it?

Comment: 1) Check your `idea.log` file (Help | Show Log in...) for possible hints. 2) Try different JDK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this bug is tracked as [IDEA-110048](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-110048). Seems that this behavior is caused by particular combinations of Java and video drivers. You can check for possible solutions in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

it' s a bug in ubuntu/compiz. Upgrade your OS to newest versions wit h latest drivers. I recommend Arch Linux